# Kotlin data classes, varying depending on type property

Tags: kotlin

In TypeScript, we have [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). In a few words, it allows the typing analyzer to narrow down to a subtype depending on a property of this item.

I need to parse a JSON response from Notion API, in which there is the schema definition of my database.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "%3FwQU",
    "name": "Groupe",
    "type": "select",
    "select": {
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "ve;X",
          "name": "Gorets",
          "color": "green"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "j%3BQq",
    "name": "Lieu",
    "type": "rich_text",
    "rich_text": {}
  },
]
```

in our case, `type` is the discriminant.

How to create a structure that allows me to parse the raw json into something typesafe ?

This is what I have so far:

```kt
enum class PropertyType(val type: String) {
    Select(type = "select"),
    Date(type = "date"),
    RichText(type = "rich_text")
}

interface BaseProperty {
    val id: String
    val name: String
    val type: PropertyType
}

val properties: List<Property>

// There must be an easier way ?
sealed class Property: BaseProperty {
    data class Select(override val id: String, override val name: String, override val type: PropertyType): Property()
    data class Date(override val id: String, override val name: String, override val type: PropertyType): Property()
}

// I'm using kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonTransformingSerializer to transform the value
object TransformProperties: JsonTransformingSerializer<Map<String, JsonObject>>(MapSerializer(String.serializer(), JsonObject.serializer())) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        element.jsonObject.values.forEach {
            val obj = it.jsonObject;
            // Same, is there an easier way ?
            val id = obj["id"].toString()
            val name = obj["name"].toString()
            val type = obj["type"].toString()
            when (type) {
                PropertyType.Select.name -> Property.Select(id, name, PropertyType.valueOf(type))
                PropertyType.Date.name -> Property.Date(id, name, PropertyType.valueOf(type))
            }
        }
        return super.transformDeserialize(element)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to achieve this. What is the best practice on this pattern?

**Update:**

Following the recommandations from @simon-jacobs , I updated my classes as follows:

```kt
@Serializable
sealed class BaseProperty {
    abstract val id: String
    abstract val name: String
    abstract val type: String
}

@Serializable
data class SelectOption(val id: String, val name: String, val color: String)

@Serializable
@SerialName("select")
data class PropertySelect(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String,
    val options: List<SelectOption> = listOf(),
    override val type: String = PropertyType.Select.name
): BaseProperty()

@Serializable
@SerialName("date")
data class PropertyDate(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String,
    override val type: String = PropertyType.Date.name
): BaseProperty()

@Serializable
@SerialName("rich_text")
data class PropertyRichText(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String,
    override val type: String = PropertyType.RichText.name
): BaseProperty()
```

However, there is an issue when serializing objects of type Kotlin is unaware of, for example the error `Polymorphic serializer was not found for class discriminator 'last_edited_time'` seems to crash because no serializer is bound to it. Is it possible to default or simply ignore it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deal with this in Kotlin is good old-fashioned polymorphism.

The [Kotlin serialization library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master) gives you all you need (and I doubt very much whether you will need `JsonTransformingSerializer` or to write too much clunky code).

The library is geared around automatically producing serialized forms of Kotlin objects for you, and providing the code to serialize and deserialize. For the most part, you should just be able to write normal Kotlin objects and the serialization library will do the hard work for you.

Read the [Serialization Guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md): it is a well-written piece of documentation.

For your JSON responses, you can do the following:

1. Define a (preferably [sealed](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes)<sup>1</sup>) base class representing all the objects that can arrive as JSON responses. Put as many shared properties in this object as possible (I'd recommend using `abstract` properties here);
2. Define subtypes for each type of possible response;
3. Put the JSON properties as constructor parameters of the subtypes, marking them `val` so they become class properties. For the most part, Kotlin types will serialize as JSON types as you expect;
4. Define further types as necessary to represent the form of the sub-objects in the JSON, and use them as the properties of your first-order types;
5. Mark all classes as [`@Serializable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-serializable/);
6. Use the [`SerialName`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#custom-subclass-serial-name) annotation so that the subclasses produce the correct `type` discriminant on serialization;
7. Now test out your work and the automatically generated serializers by calling [`encodeToString`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#json-encoding) on some sample objects to see if the JSON output matches what you want. Call `encodeToString` with the base class type as it is in the base class scope you wish to use the serialization (ie all the JSON responses are of the base class type). (It's also a great opportunity to do a bit of test-driven development); and
8. Possibly [hand-write](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers) some serializers if the automatic serializers aren't generating precisely what you need.

It's a nice library to use once you get the hang of it and I think you will find satisfaction getting it all to work together.

---

<sup>1</sup>Making the base class sealed means the library can automatically find the subclasses when you serialize or deserialize the base class. Otherwise, you need to [register](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#open-polymorphism) the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, this already helped me a lot. There was an edit in my post, but I'm very new to Kotlin projects and there are a lot of things I am unaware of. I'm trying to read the response from Retrofit, but I don't know where I can configure the serializer per request (Android training teaches you to configure your Retrofit instance in your app container). I'll update my post with the new code, but now I'm still blocked near the end. I don't need to implement all the serializers, can I have a default one ?

Comment: There looks to be a way of implementing default serializers: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#default-polymorphic-type-handler-for-deserialization. However if you are looking to get this finished, I suspect it's quicker and easier just to write the missing subclasses. You are nearly there!

Comment: Thanks again, I implemented the missing ones, as I'm only using 4 types out of the 14 available, it was indeed faster this way even though a default one would have been more practical, in case I need a new field soon. I also needed the `JsonTransformingSerializer` to transform the value which was a map of my items, and not a list of items. I couldn't find the built-in serializer for that

Comment: If a JSON map/object has unknown keys, it can be typed by `Map<String, T>` where `T` is the (serializable) type of the values. If you know the keys in advance you can write a class instead as before. If the map also has changing types for values, you can again represent them with a sealed class hierarchy. Writing your own serializers is a last resort and only needed when there is inflexibility in the Kotlin classes (ie, you will always be able to write classes that serialize automatically to any given JSON).